# how to make my jtable responsive

Tags: jtable, responsive

I am using jtable to show records. The problem is it is not responsive, i am having lot of columns in my jtable. I would like to make jtable as a responsive one for mobile view and desktop view. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you already found out how to do it?